# Regex pattern to not equal 0

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I want to pass values those are not equal zero (0). What is the best performing regex pattern for this ?

Comment: Regex, based on the context you've given, seems like weird complicated overkill for something like this. I think normal logic operators (ex. if (a != 0)) is probably more than enough to get the job done. However, that's just based on what you've said, which isn't much, lol.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
[^0]+
```

Means: Any character besides zero must occur at least once